# How can I make Watson Assistant recognize 3 hours as 3 hours later?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Currently when I input 3 hours, Watson Assistant system entity @sys-time is able to recognize it as 3 am
but I need the Watson Assistant to recognize it as 3 hours later which @sys-time gives me 9 pm (if current time is 6pm).

Action: User input 3 hours

Result: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ9h3.png)

> @sys-time:03:00:00

Expect (if current time is 6pm): [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJpeo.png)

> @sys-time:21:00:00

Comment: Watson Assistant has some date arithmetic functions. In your case, it recognizes 3 hours as 3 hours. You can access both the input and variations of the recognized intents and entities and then apply your specific logic.

Comment: so it means that im only able to apply specific logic to it and not able to modify the system entity logic, am i right?

Comment: It is a SYSTEM entitity, correct. :) You can define your own entities or use system entities as input for date computation. Current time plus detected hours from input equals future time.

Comment: Ok thanks, got it working as I expected. Thanks again!